# error 127 found while installing gtk themes in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, error-handling

```
dpkg: error processing package flat-remix-gnome (--configure):
 installed flat-remix-gnome package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 flat-remix-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error by starting my laptop in recovery mode. Then I selected dpkg and installed broken packages. Then I restarted my laptop and the error was solved.